# Trouble rendering data to page with React

Tags: javascript, express, reactjs

I'm trying to pull data from heroku database and render to the page. All information is correctly being logged, however, returning the data is giving me the issue. Comparing values of question_id and answer_id are working correctly. I want to be able to render a question with all answers related to that question  (i.e e.question + f.answer)

What is wrong with my returns in the map and filter methods?

```
class Questions extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        finddata: [],
        allQuestions: [],
        relAnswers: [],
    }
}

componentWillMount(){
    this.renderQuestions();
    this.checkNewUrl();
}
checkNewUrl(){
    let newUrl = 'https://project-overflow-db.herokuapp.com/QA/1'
    axios.get(newUrl)
    .then((res) => {
        console.log('whats new return-->', res.data);
        let alldata = res.data
        this.setState({
            finddata: res.data,
            allQuestions: alldata.questions,
            relAnswers: alldata.answers
        })
    })
}

renderNew(){
    console.log('does this STATE SHOW', this.state.finddata);
    let x = this.state.finddata;
    console.log('THIS IS THE XXXXXXX-->', x);
    console.log('CONVERT TO ARRAY', Object.values(x));

    return (this.state.allQuestions.map((e) =>{
        // return <h1> {e.question} </h1>
        console.log('SHOW ME THE MONEY',e.question);
        return this.state.relAnswers.filter((f) => {
                if(f.question_id === e.question_id){
                    console.log('show me the QUESTION', e.question)      
                    console.log('got it', f.answer)
                    // return <div {f.answer} </div>
                }
            })
})
    )
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <h1 style={styles}> {this.props.match.params.id} </h1>

            {this.renderNew()}  

            {this.props.handleSubmit}
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default Questions
```